# Onsen - navigator and sliding menu - function on prepush doesn't working

Tags: slidingmenu, onsen-ui, navigator

I have a big problem.
I want to use navigator and sliding menu. Then I need to have some behaviour on postpush.

This is my codepen example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxgpVo

If you stay in Home and navigate from this point, then you see the console.log .
But if you change from the sliding menu and go to Products, then the console.log doesn't working and if you return in Home doesn't working here anymore.

I create 2 navigator with the same name. This is a right thing? Maybe this can be the problem?

```
<ons-template id="home.html">
  <ons-navigator page="page0.html" var="myNav"></ons-navigator>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="products.html">
  <ons-navigator page="page_products.html" var="myNav"></ons-navigator>
</ons-template>
```

I cannot figure out how can I create a working example.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain what is happening there (or, at least, what I understand):

The root of your project is an `ons-sliding-menu` and then you have two childs, one per menu entry (*home* and *products*). Each child is an `ons-navigator` with the same name, but it should not matter since they will not be "alive" at the same time.
When you are in *home* and use `menu.setMainPage('products.html')` you are killing *home*'s navigator and creating *product*'s navigator. Your events only work in the very beginning because you associate them to home's navigator on `ons.ready()` **only the first time**. Therefore, when you use `setMainPage` you are destroying the navigator that has those events, and the new navigators won't have them.

Instead of associating the events to the navigator on `ons.ready`, you can specify the postpush/prepush events in the creation of the navigator itself. There are attributes to do that explained in the docs: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#attributes

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have updated my codepen. I have a question: can I put a function inside the navigator's attribute?
If you see the example, home doesn't work but products is working good.
Thank you

Comment: The expressions are parsed in AngularJS, so it will only admit Angular's $scope variables :/ . You can check here how it works: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/QwePKV

Comment: With jQuery and Onsen UI 1.3.0 you can do something similar:

`$(document).on('ons-navigator:prepush', 'ons-navigator', function(event) {
  console.log("Pushed!");
});`